# MDX: How to access currently selected dimension members?

Tags: ssas, mdx

I'm trying to create a measure in `MDX` to get the first day in the selected period (I have a YMD date dimension). I'm using `EXISTING` function to get the selected members. It's working fine if I only select one dimension member in Excel pivot table filter. However, as soon as I select multiple members (Example: 2012 & 2013 together), the `EXISTING` function is not working as expected.

I've created another measure to debug and see what is going on. The measure is defined as:

> SetToStr(EXISTING([Date].[Date YMD].[Year].members))

If I have only one dimension member selected, this works fine, I get this back:

> {[Date].[Date YMD].[All].[2013]}

However, as soon as I select 2012 and 2013 together, I get a list of all dimension members back:

```
{[Date].[Date YMD].[All].[N/A],[Date].[Date YMD].[All].[2007],[Date].[Date YMD].[All].[2008],[Date].[Date YMD].[All].[2009],[Date].[Date YMD].[All].[2010],[Date].[Date YMD].[All].[2011],[Date].[Date YMD].[All].[2012],[Date].[Date YMD].[All].[2013],[Date].[Date YMD].[All].[2014]}
```

The EXISTING function seems to work only when a single member is selected?

--

Update:

Maybe I was not clear enough in the original post. The problem I'm facing is getting the first and last date member **if the date dimension is being filtered (in an Excel pivot table filter) and multiple date members are selected in the filter** (example: when years 2012 & 2013 are selected together).

I've tried using the solution from here: http://bimic.blogspot.com/2011/07/mdx-rewrite-query-with-currentmember.html, but to no success.

I've created 2 measures now:

1. First Day Single:

> ```
> HEAD(
> DESCENDANTS(
>     [Date].[Date YMD].CURRENTMEMBER,
>     [Date].[Date YMD].[Day]
>     ),
> 1
> ).ITEM(0).member_value
> ```

1. First Day Multiple Years

> ```
> MIN(EXISTING [Date].[Date YMD].[Year].members, [Measures].[First Day Single])
> ```

Unfortunately I can't include a screenshot directly. You can see it on this link: http://social.msdn.microsoft.com/Forums/getfile/446659

As you can see, the measures work when a single year is selected in the pivot table filter, but don't work when you select more than one year.

Comment: What tools are you using to add this new measure? Are you writing this MDX via SQL-Server Management Studio, or using Excel with a connection to your cube?

Comment: I'm using OLAP Pivottables extensions.

Comment: Doesn't the first day depend on the current granularity? Say if you have 2 years selected 2012, and 2013, it will select the first day of the first year - which is 1st Jan 2012. Isn't that correct?

Comment: Hi Stephen! Yes, I expected to get back the first day of the first year (e.g. 1.1.2012), but this is not the case. The code I've posted does not work if multiple years are selected. Take a look at the screenshot: http://social.msdn.microsoft.com/Forums/getfile/446659

Comment: @StephenBorg that is what we expect but not the observed behaviour

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Really old topic, but I am posting my solution here as I haven't found the solution elsewhere:

Using dynamic set seems to have done the trick for me as will be populated only with members in context:

```
CREATE DYNAMIC SET [LastUpdateSet]
AS
    TAIL(
        NONEMPTY(
                [LastUpdateDate].[Date].ALLMEMBERS
                , [Measures].[Quantity]
        )
    , 1)
;
CREATE MEMBER CURRENTCUBE.[Measures].[LastUpdateQuantity]
 AS (
        [LastUpdateSet].item(0)
        , [Measures].[Quantity]
    )
;
```

Comment: It's been a while, but I just had the same problem at another client and this workaround seems to do the trick. Thank you!

Answer (score 4):

In my cube and via management studio I can write a script like this to create measures that return numeric values based on the first day and last day of each month:

```
WITH 
SET [Last12Months] AS
    TAIL ( 
        [Date].[Date - Calendar Month].[Calendar Month].members, 
        12)
MEMBER [Measures].[FirstDay] AS
    HEAD(
        DESCENDANTS(
            [Date].[Date - Calendar Month].CURRENTMEMBER,
            [Date].[Date - Calendar Month].[Calendar Day]
            ),
        1
        ).ITEM(0).member_value
MEMBER [Measures].[LastDay] AS
    TAIL(
        DESCENDANTS(
            [Date].[Date - Calendar Month].CURRENTMEMBER,
            [Date].[Date - Calendar Month].[Calendar Day]
            ),
        1
        ).ITEM(0).member_value
SELECT
    {[Measures].[FirstDay],[Measures].[LastDay]} ON 0,
    [Last12Months] ON 1
FROM [MyCube]
```

We use `Office 2010` but using the `OLAP Pivottables extensions` add-in I can add the following two measures to my pivottable:

1.`[Measures].[FirstDay]`

```
HEAD(
    DESCENDANTS(
        [Date].[Date - Calendar Month].CURRENTMEMBER,
        [Date].[Date - Calendar Month].[Calendar Day]
        ),
    1
    ).ITEM(0).member_value
```

2.`[Measures].[LastDay]`

```
TAIL(
    DESCENDANTS(
        [Date].[Date - Calendar Month].CURRENTMEMBER,
        [Date].[Date - Calendar Month].[Calendar Day]
        ),
    1
    ).ITEM(0).member_value
```

Now whatever I use in Rows I get the correct answer from the pivot:

[image]

---

**EDIT**

If I manipulate the pivot so that our date dimension is in the pivot's filter and then go for multi-select of 2013 and 2014 it seems that the `mdx' which excel is using is the following:

```
WITH 
MEMBER [Measures].[FirstDay] as
 HEAD (
  DESCENDANTS ( [Date].[Date - Calendar Month].CURRENTMEMBER, [Date].[Date - Calendar Month].[Calendar Day] )
  , 1
 ).ITEM( 0 ).member_value
MEMBER [Measures].[LastDay] as
 TAIL (
  DESCENDANTS ( [Date].[Date - Calendar Month].CURRENTMEMBER, [Date].[Date - Calendar Month].[Calendar Day] )
  , 1
 ).ITEM( 0 ).member_value
SELECT
  { [Measures].[FirstDay], [Measures].[LastDay] }  ON COLUMNS
FROM 
   (
   SELECT 
     ({ [Date].[Date - Calendar Month].[Calendar Year].&[2012], 
        [Date].[Date - Calendar Month].[Calendar Year].&[2013] }) ON COLUMNS
   FROM [OurCube]
   )
```

I think the *context* of the function `CURRENTMEMBER` in the custom measures of this script will be lost because of the sub-select.

Comment: I've tried your solution and it's having the same problem as my measure. Your measures "FirstDay" and "LastDay" work fine **in the context of a single date member** (if you have date dimension on rows and measures on columns). However, if you put date dimension in the pivot table filter and select multiple date dimension members in the filter (e.g. if you select 2 years together, let's say 2012 & 2013), then the "FirstDay" will always return first member in the date dimension without applying the filter (in my case 1.1.1900) and "LastDay" the last one (in my case 31.12.2014).

Comment: Hi saso - looks from the edit to the OP that my answer has helped a bit... thanking a poster for their answer usually involves upping the answer +1! I could have a further play around.

Comment: Hi! Unfortunately I can't upvote an answer yet. :/ I'm quite new to stackoverflow and I don't have enough reputation yet... I will play around some more, thanks again for helping out!

Comment: I see what you mean - Excel takes the combined members and uses them in a subselect rather than a `WHERE` clause. Think some sort of workaround will be the only solution.

Answer (score 0):

There is a workaround for your problem described here: http://sqlblog.com/blogs/mosha/archive/2007/09/26/how-to-detect-subselect-inside-mdx-calculations-aka-multiselect-in-excel-2007.aspx. But, as the writer (one of the developers of SSAS) writes, " the solution is neither elegant nor efficient". Anyway, it needs another measure group to be added to the cube, and a stored procedure to be written.